# How to get a full CSS code for an element

Tags: css, element, inspect

I am new to CSS and just learned how to inspect an element. My question is how can i get a whole/full CSS code for an element?

Let say i need a full css code for a form (https://townends.co.uk) please see search form on homepage, How can i get that whole code for this module?

Thanks in advance.

A

Answer (score 0):

Right click -> View Page Source from site.

Then find "< link rel='stylesheet'" keyword. You have all the css files associated.

Comment: Hi Still looking forward to get help please. Thanks everyone here.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you could use the dev tools in your browser. They can be super helpful for seeing what actually is affecting different elements in your site. depending on which browser you are using the shortcut for it is different. My favorite suite of in-browser dev tools is in Firefox(check out the developers edition of Firefox as well).

From within the dev tools of Firefox you can click on the arrow pointing into a box from the highest level tabs. This allows you to hover over any element on your page and display the classes and ids affecting the element as well as the rules being used on the element in the dev tool partition of your screen at the bottom. There are many more useful tools in browsers so explore it a little and it will probably improve your productivity.

Comment: I want to style my form as above link provided but cant figure out the exact CSS. Kindly advise if i need php customisation or simply CSS Code will do the job. Here is my website link; www.fairlandestates.co.uk

Thanks in advance for help